# Differences and benefits of PageModel vs ViewData in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I cannot find any clear explanation on this.

I am trying to understand the differences and benefits of `PageModel` vs `ViewData` as a tool to pass data from C# code to `cshtml` for rendering in Razor Pages. What would be an impact on performance, reliability, testability?

Using ASP.NET 6.

Comment: On `PageModel` you have properties, which can be set automatically during a `POST`. And they are typed.

Comment: But looking only through delivering data from code to page, is there any difference in performance. I understand that `PageModel` is more reliable as typed.

Comment: I don't think there's much difference in performance, but you often have to cast values in `ViewData` to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PageModel is strong typing: IntelliSense and compile-time checking when accessing properties of the Model in a content page.

ViewData can be used as the ViewData attribute on model properties.
ViewData is shared with the layout page (and any partial pages called by the content page or the layout), so the attribute makes it easy to pass typed data from the PageModel to the layout page or partials without having to explicitly assign it to the ViewData dictionary.

Example:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [ViewData]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Message = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Add   `<h2>@ViewData["Message"]</h2>` into layout page.

[image]